# What does the '(( 10#$H > 5 ))' mean in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am confused about the following code snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash

H=$(date +%H); 
if (( 10#$H > 5 ))
then 
        # do something
else 
        # do something else
fi
```

What does the `(( 10#$H > 5 ))` mean in above code snippet?

Comment: Have you tried reading [the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)? What does it say?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `10#$H` means to expand the number using base 10.

This is probably done to remove any leading zeros from the date due to the fact that bash will interpret the number in base 8 (octal).

Example:

```
$ echo "$(( 08 < 5 ))"
bash: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
```

> ARITHMETIC EVALUATION: **Constants with a leading `0` are interpreted as octal numbers.**  A leading `0x` or `0X` denotes hexadecimal.  Otherwise, numbers take the form `[base#]n`, where `base` is a decimal number between `2` and  `64`  representing
>          the arithmetic base and `n` is a number in that `base`.  If `base#` is omitted, then base `10` is used.  The digits greater than `9` are represented by the lowercase letters, the uppercase letters, `@`, and `_`, in that order.  If `base` is less than or equal to `36`, lowercase and uppercase letters may be used interchangeably to represent numbers between 10 and 35.
>
> **<sub>source: `man bash`</sub>**

Comment: … because the leading `0` will cause bash to interpret the number as octal, which is the wrong base.

Comment: Might want to add that zeros are to be removed because values are octal if they do....

Comment: @Petesh - Updated answer

Comment: Note: the following `[[ "$H" < "05" ]]` will give a more readable result and does string comparison.

Comment: very nice answer!

Comment: @kvantour String comparison won't work right with numbers that aren't the same length (in digits). For instance, `[[ "1" < "05" ]]` is false, because "1" comes after "0" in character sorting order. In this case, `$H` *might* be guaranteed to be two digits long, but it's best not to count on it.

Comment: @GordonDavisson why would you not count on it? Are there implementations of `date` where `%H` is not a 2-digit number?

Comment: In some ways a less obscure way to code that would be `${H#0}` though it only works for a single leading zero (which should however be sufficient here).